# Average instruction time

Tags: time, operating-system, instructions

Lets say we have an average of one page fault every 20,000,000 instructions, a normal instruction takes 2 nanoseconds, and a page fault causes the instruction to take an additional 10 milliseconds. What is the average instruction time, taking page faults into account?

Comment: Someone needed to ask this question here?  Really?

Comment: There is a FAQ entry on the "Homework" problem. No clear consensus last time I looked. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230510/homework-on-stackoverflow

Comment: I just found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230510?sort=votes#sort-top The majority opinion includes "Try to give suggestions that will lead the asker in the correct direction rather than providing a ready-made answer."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20,000,000 instructions, one of them will page-fault

Therefore, the 20,000,000 instructions will take

```
  (2 nanoseconds * 20,000,000) + 10 milliseconds
```

get the result (which is the total time for 20,000,000 instructions), and divide it by the number of instructions to get the time-per-instruction.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the average instruction time, taking page faults into account?

The average instruction time is the total time, divided by the number of instructions.

So: what's the *total* time for 20,000,000 instructions?

Answer (score 0):

2.5 nanoseconds? Pretty simple arithmetic, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

If 1 in 20,000,000 instructions causes a page fault then you have a page fault rate of:

```
Page Fault Rate = (1/20000000)
```

You can then calculate your average time per instruction:

```
Average Time = (1 - Page Fault Rate) * 2 ns + (Page Fault Rate * 10 ms)
```

Comes to 2.5 ns / instruction